# Clear() or Dispose() to clear dataset assigned to new Dataset() in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

What should I use to clear DataSet which I assign to `new Dataset()` on every new SQL call in my C# code (Windows Mobile Compact Framework)?

At the moment I am using Clear(), however I am not sure if I should be using Dispose instead. What would be proper choice for this?

Some code:

Inside frmA (main form where I perform SQL search of database) I save my search result into Database and if count is greater than 0, I go to another form `frmNewWork` to do some work with found data:

```
// search SQL
// declare connectionString and command... 
SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(mCommand);
modFunctions.tempDataset = new NEWDataSet();
adapter.Fill(modFunctions.tempDataset, "item");
foundCount = modFunctions.tempDataset.item.Count;

// Goes off to another form to do somework with that dataset
if (foundCount > 0)
{
    frmNewWork myForm = new frmNewWork();
    myForm.ShowDialog()
}
```

Now... once I return from `myForm`, I want to clear that database, and I do that inside form A `GotFocus` function:

```
private void frmA_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clear prior tempDataset (was .Clear() originally)
    modFunctions.tempDataset.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Post code, give context. Btw Clear(), Dispose() and new DataSet() serves different purposes

Comment: Sorry about that, I added some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points

1) If you want to clear the Dataset after other form which is shown using ShowDialog() method. You can do it just after your `myForm.ShowDialog();` statement.

2) If `ASTSDataSet` is unmanaged call Dispose. Otherwise do not do anything, GC will take care.

Comment: If it implements `IDisposable`, always call `Dispose`.

Answer (score 3):

Write the Code like this..

```
using(DataSet ds= new Dataset()
{
}
```

No need to Worry About Dispose.

You can also look at this link.
    http://www.csharptuts.net/dataset-in-c/